# How to skip update for git submodules for which we do not have (read/write/admin) access

Tags: git

I have multiple submodules in my repository.
I have access only to some of those submodules.

I am using git command to update all the submodules at one shot.
The command I use is:

> git submodule update --remote

The problem is, when git tries to update those submodules for which I do not have access,
it throws an error and stops there.
The remaining submodules do not get updated even though I have permission for those.

Is there a built-in command by which I can request update only for the submodules for which I have permission?

I am looking for a generic command that I can use in multiple repositories.
So, I would like to refrain from hard coding branch names in my "git update" command.

Comment: Try `git -c submodule.<name>.update=none submodule update --remote` where `name` is the submodule name you want to skip. Multiple `-c submodule.<name>.update=none` can be specified.

Comment: Then try `git submodule foreach <command>` to simulate `git submodule update --remote`. According to the manual, `adding || : to the end of the command` can prevent the processing from being terminated when the command's exit code is not 0.

Comment: @ElpieKay, yes I understand that. But is there a way to do it without hardcoding submodule names in my command?
PS: I have edited my question after your comment.

Comment: @ElpieKay, do you mean something like this:  
**git submodule foreach --recursive git submodule update --remote || :**

Answer (score 1):

With ElpieKay's suggestion, I could resolve my issue with the below command

```
git submodule foreach --recursive 'git pull origin master || :'
```